# How to use Link in NavItem in ReactJS without using node / import

Tags: spring, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm developing a multi page application in Spring and ReactJS without using NodeJS.

index.html:

```
<body>

    <div class='container'>
        <div id='root'>test</div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.4/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.31.5/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-bootstrap/0.24.4/ReactRouterBootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/4.2.2/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/babel" src="/public/navigation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="/public/test.js"></script>

</body>
```

test.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<div><TestNavigation /></div>, document.getElementById('root') );
```

navigation.js

```
var Navbar = ReactBootstrap.Navbar,
            Nav = ReactBootstrap.Nav,   
            NavItem = ReactBootstrap.NavItem;

var LinkContainer = ReactRouterBootstrap.LinkContainer;


class TestNavigation extends React.Component {
    navItemHandleClick() {
        console.log("NavItem Clicked")


      }

      render() {

    return (
      <div className="col-md-12">
          <Navbar id="navbar"collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav >

                        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#" >Page 1</NavItem>

                        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#" className="navLink" onClick={this.navItemHandleClick}>Page 2</NavItem>

                        <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#" className="navLink" >Page 3</NavItem>

                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not able to have link inside NavItem. I don't want to use nodejs, so import statement in js file will not work. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<Navbar.Link>` to get `nav-link` inside your `NavItem` like below

```
<NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
    <Navbar.Link>Page 1</Navbar.Link>
</NavItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked. Thanks

`<NavItem eventKey={1} ><Link className="navLink" to="/" id="navcolor">Home</Link></NavItem>`